# Standard SQL SELECT * FROM TABLE return syntax error

Tags: mysql, vb.net, syntax

I keep getting an error saying "there is an error in your sql syntax." when i use this sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM gsm_oceanwide_integration
```

**EDIT:**

To put this in context heres the code im using this query statement in (VB.net):

```
Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=" & frmLogin.txtserver.Text & ";Database=stratocast;User ID=" & frmLogin.txtusername.Text & ";Password=" & frmLogin.txtpassword.Text & ";")
Dim sqladmin As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM employee", con)
Dim sqlprojects As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM projects", con)
Dim sqlpage As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM '" & frmMain.ListBox1.SelectedItem & "';", con)

Dim ds5 As DataSet = New DataSet()
Dim DataAdapter5 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter()
Dim Comb As MySqlCommandBuilder

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    ' retrieving the Project Page.
    Try
        con.Open()
        DataAdapter5.SelectCommand = sqlpage
        DataAdapter5.Fill(ds5, "stratocast")
        DataGridView3.DataSource = ds5
        DataGridView3.DataMember = "stratocast"
        con.Close()

    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error Retrieving Project Page: " & myerror.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

on my **frmMain** form i have a listbox with a list of projects (one of them being **gsm_oceanwide_integration**) and i want to make it so that when i click on that selection it will display another form with a datagridview. this datagridview needs to be filled with data from the table i called gsm_oceanwide_integration. (like the listbox selection)

so my current query statement (including vb.net tags) is:

```
Dim sqlpage As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM '" & frmMain.ListBox1.SelectedItem & "';", con)
```

It was working earlier today, but i must have changed something in it and forgot... 
since then the best i can do is get rid of all the errors but the datagridview still won't display anything on my database. Yes, i've checked all the spelling.

---

**UPDATE 2:**
I changed my sqlpage command statement from:

```
Dim sqlpage As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM '" & frmMain.ListBox1.SelectedItem & "';", con)
```

To:

```
 Dim sqlpage As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [" & Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value & "]", con)
```

and i got a new error on another form all together but it's linked to the listbox1; the code for which is below:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedValueChanged
    Form1.indprojectname.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    Form1.Show()
End Sub
```

The error is shown in this screenshot (i thought a screen shot might be the best method for displaying the error details):
[image: ScreenShot]

the error is: (in case you couldn't read the screenshot)

> An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Also, thanks for the quick replies, sorry i couldn't update my post sooner...

Thanks!

Comment: Query looks OK to me. Are you showing us everything? As for spaces in table names, it's possible by escaping the names with back ticks (e.g., ` `my table` `, but I'd recommend against it just for readability. Use underscores instead.

Comment: Your query does not end with the standard delimiter `;`. Are you using some kind of customized delimiter?

Comment: `gsm_oceanwide_integration` is a reserved word, duh!

Comment: @ajreal, the ";" is not needed, unless there's another query following this one.

Comment: @John -- proof it and you deserved +1, not sure what is the actual environment for OP

Comment: I have 1000's of lines of MySQL queries with no `;` in sight, both using Delphi and in DBForge etc. The only place I know of where MySQL goes apeshit on `;` is in stored procs. **@daniel11, Is this a code sample from inside a stored proc?**

Comment: @ajreal, the environment is vb.net

Comment: @Johan -- i don't know if this is correct or not but i read somewhere online when i first started learning SQL that semi colons (sorry i don't know how to do block quotes in comments) should only appear in Query statements to separate multiple expressions,parameters,or statements. And to answer your question, no i wrote this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the single quote before your double quote around the table name coming in from your listbox?  That should not be there.  You have:

```
Dim sqlpage As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM '" & frmMain.ListBox1.SelectedItem & "';", con)
```

It should be:

```
Dim sqlpage As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & frmMain.ListBox1.SelectedItem & ";", con)
```

Comment: when i apply the changes you suggested above i get an error saying (There is an error in your SQL syntax near " line 1.)..... im trying to select all columns from the table with the name that is specified in the listbox selected item. am i doing it right?

Comment: When you set a breakpoint and debug, what is the value of SelectedItem?

Comment: Actually, now that I look at the code again, I would re-Write this as:  Dim sqlpage As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [" & Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value & "]", con)   Using the .Value or .Text attribute depending on what is stored in your list.

Comment: as far as i know the only way to set a breakpoint is when the error is related to my vb.net application... however this is not the case as it is an SQL syntax error. The error is displayed in a message box because i have a try and catch block implemented. when i get rid of it i don't get any errors but the datagridview is empty as usual...

Comment: Yes, it is a sql syntax error but my experience has been that if I am getting that error and your other -nearly identical syntax (shown above with hard coded table names)- works, then the control is probably not returning what I am expecting and by checking that value (or by response writing the string to the browser), I find what the control is actually returning and most of the time see the error.

Comment: ok i tried your suggestion above and now i get a different error which i will add to my original post as "UPDATE 2"

Answer (score 2):

Steer clear of any adding special characters in your table names or field names. Stick to a convention such as...

`myFieldName` - known as camel casing or...

`my_field_name` - just use underscores

As for the sql statement I can't see anything immediately wrong with it. Is the table name correct?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your query about spaces in table names:

Short Answer - yes but no

However, I would take a look at the [MySQL documentation on Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

Also as mentioned in the comments, spaces are allowed as a table indentifer using quoted indentifiers but I would not encourage the use of them, mainly for readability reasons.

As for your query, would require more information, such as your list of tables.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as the asker, but for a different reason.

I named one of my tables `order`. When executing a query against this table results in sql thinking that my table name was the keyword `ORDER`.

i.e. `select * from order;` returns

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "order"
LINE 1: select * from order;
```

To get around this I was able to surround my table name in double quotation marks and successfully run my search.

`select * from "order";` works!